# Has inheritance become bad?

Tags: database, inheritance, serialization, remoting

Personally, I think inheritance is a great tool, that, when applied reasonably, can greatly simplify code.

However, I seems to me that many modern tools dislike inheritance. Let's take a simple example: Serialize a class to XML. As soon as inheritance is involved, this can easily turn into a mess. Especially if you're trying to serialize a derived class using the base class serializer.

Sure, we can work around that. Something like a `KnownType` attribute and stuff. Besides being an itch in your code that you have to remember to update every time you add a derived class, that fails, too, if you receive a class from outside your scope that was not known at compile time. (Okay, in some cases you can still work around that, for instance using the NetDataContract serializer in .NET. Surely a certain advancement.)

In any case, the basic principle still exists: Serialization and inheritance don't mix well. Considering the huge list of programming strategies that became possible and even common in the past decade, I feel tempted to say that inheritance should be avoided in areas that relate to serialization (in particular remoting and databases).

Does that make sense? Or am messing things up? How do you handle inheritance and serialization?

Comment: Would this qualify as another reason to prefer composition over inheritance?

Comment: I believe that composition and inheritance each have their own application. If inheritance is the better choice of the two, then I really want to use it. I __hate__ it when I'm compelled to use an inferior design because the technology does not support the better, the _correct_ design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed a few gotcha with inheritance and serialization. One is that it leads to an **asymmetry** between serialization/deserialization. If a class is subclassed, this will work transparently during serialization, but will fail during deserialization, unless the deserialization is made aware of the new class. That's why we have tags such as `@SeeAlso` to annotate data for XML serialization.

These problems are however not new about inheritance. It's frequently discussed under the terminology **open/closed world**. Either you consider you know the whole world and classes, or you might be in a case where new classes are added by third-parties. In a closed world assumption, serialization isn't much a problem. It's more problematic in an open world assumption.

But inheritance and the open world assumption have anyway other gotchas. E.g. if you remove a `protected` method in your classes and refactor accordingly, how can you ensure that there isn't a third party class that was using it? In an open world, the public **and internal** API of your classes must be considered as frozen once made available to other. And you must take great care to evolve the system.

There are other more technical internal details of how serialization works that can be surprising. That's for Java, but I'm pretty sure .NET has similarities. E.g. [Serialization Killer](http://gbracha.blogspot.com/2010/02/serialization-killer.html), by Gilad Bracha, or [Serialization and security manager](http://blog.cr0.org/2010/04/javacalypse.html) bug exploit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on my current project and this might not be the best way, but I created a service layer of sorts for it and its own classes.  I think it came out being named ObjectToSerialized translator and a couple of interfaces.  Typically this was a one to one (the "object" and "serialized" had the exact same properties) so adding something to the interface would let you know "hey, add this over here too".

I want to say I had a IToSerialized interface with a simple method on it for generic purposes and used automapper for most of the conversions.  Sure, it's a bit more code but hey whatever, it worked and doesn't gum up other things.